# RabbitMQ Routing Keys

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

Good Day.

Is there a way to retrieve routing keys for an existing exchange (fanout or topic) via the browser based UI?

I don't have access to the client source code (producer) to see which routing keys are being sent to the model.

Thank you.

Edit:
The idea is to try and latch on to an existing fanout exchange (which I cannot reconfigure). I want to create a new exchange, bind it to this one and only filter out certain messages.

Comment: To get exchange bindings use http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/source es: http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my_exchange/bindings/source

Comment: Your Sir, Mr Gas are my hero :) Thanks so much, you are correct. i'm unable to mark your comment as being correct though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html):

> http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/vhost/name/bindings/source
>
> A list of all bindings in which a given exchange is the source.

for example:

http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/my_exchange/bindings/source

```
[
   {
      "source":"my_exchange",
      "vhost":"/",
      "destination":"my_queue",
      "destination_type":"queue",
      "routing_key":"my_routkey",
      "arguments":{

      },
      "properties_key":"my_routkey"
   }
]
```